# Is becoming like God good thing?

Tags: adam, attributes-of-god, fall

Genesis 3:22. Please notice the two different translation samples below. The same scripture but different outcomes.

Then the Lord God said, “Behold, the man has become like one of Us, knowing good and evil; and now, he might stretch out his hand, and take also from the tree of life, and eat, and live forever”—
Genesis 3:22 - https://www.biblegateway.com/passage?search=Genesis%203:22&version=NASB1995

Shouldn't becoming like God be a good thing? Why then did God drive Adam and Eve out of the garden?

And Jehovah God saith, `Lo, the man was as one of Us, as to the knowledge of good and evil; and now, lest he sends forth his hand, and have taken also of the tree of life, and eaten, and lived to the age,' --
Genesis 3:22 - https://www.biblegateway.com/passage?search=Genesis%203:22&version=YLT

After all didn't God create Adam in His own image? So yes Adam was once like God.

How do we reconcile the two? Which one is the right translation? Should we get our Hebrew dictionary or call the pastor? No! Let's just take a look at what was said in each of these two translations.

The first translation, God says:  Behold man has become like one of us, knowing good and evil.

What did man do to become like God?
Man sinned and became like God? WHAT?

The second translation God says: Lo man WAS as one of us to knowledge of good and evil.

There is nothing wrong with knowing good and evil as God has always known good and evil. I know that  committing adultery is evil and so do you. This does not mean that you and I have sinned. Just knowing it. It is only wrong or evil if you and I act on this knowledge. Just like Adam and Eve. They were given the knowledge of good and evil by God prior to the fall.

Then the Lord God took the man and put him into the garden of Eden to cultivate it and keep it. The Lord God commanded the man, saying, “From any tree of the garden you may eat freely; but from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat from it you will surely die.”
Genesis 2:15-17 - https://www.biblegateway.com/passage?search=Genesis%202:15-17&version=NASB1995

Notice the lie that the serpent tells Eve.

For God knows that in the day you eat from it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and evil.” This was a lie.
Genesis 3:5 - https://www.biblegateway.com/passage?search=Genesis%203:5&version=NASB1995

He told her the very opposite of what God told her. God said not to eat or you will die. The serpent says eat and you will be like God.
They did not become like God by partaking evil.

God knows both good and evil. He has never acted on evil. God is love. So we can see that man was once like God knowing both good and evil.
Don’t let pride keep you from the truth of God's Word.
Thank you for listening.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to BH.SE - please do take the Site Tour to find out more about how the site works. I've closed it as it doesn't actually read as a clear question for people to answer. If you want you could trim this down to a definite question and then [answer it yourself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if that's what you're meaning to do here.

Comment: Sorry your question got closed. I think it is a good thing. The issue is trying to do it your own way on your own timeline instead of doing it God's way and waiting on the Lord. I personally think that God intended for them to eat of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, but according to His plan - when He assessed they were ready. So the evil was rebellion against God as opposed to simply eating from the tree. It's like how Moses died for striking the rock. There is nothing wrong with striking rocks. The sin was disobeying God.